# Rotating a QByteArray

Tags: c++, arrays, qt, camera, rotation

I want to rotate a Camera in a viewfinder. My idea is to get the QByteArray and rotate it, so the pixels are shown mirrored in X and Y direction.
So if my array looks like this:

```
5 2 6 8
3 5 2 1
6 7 4 5
3 2 1 7
```

it should looks like this:

```
7 1 2 3
5 4 7 6
1 2 5 3
8 6 2 5
```

Can somebody tell me how I can do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use std::reserve like this

```
#include <algorithm> 

QByteArray reverse = barr; 
std::reverse(reverse.constBegin(), reverse.constEnd());
```

or use this

```
QByteArray reverse;
std::reverse_copy(barr.constBegin(), barr.constEnd(), reverse.begin());
```

Comment: I think you meant std::reverse

Comment: Neither of the above snippets works. The first won't compile, the second results in an empty array. This works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50257560/1570669

Answer (score 0):

How are you accessing your `QByteArray`?

If iterators are an acceptable solution you could do something like this:

```
for(std::reverse_iterator<char*> rBegin(myQByteArray.data() + myQByteArray.size()); rBegin != std::reverse_iterator<char*>(myQByteArray.data()); ++rBegin){
    std::cout << *rBegin << " ";
}
```

Note that if you want to use the `const char* QByteArray::data()` call you can simply initialize your `std::reverse_iterator`s with `const` in the template:

```
std::reverse_iterator<const char*> rBegin(myQByteArray.data())
```

Comment: It gave me a error about the std::cout.. is there a mistake? 

Should it be count?
But then there is the mistake that the list of the formal parameters is not right

Comment: @Der_Pätti I don't have `QByteArray` on this system, but you can see this working with a `const char*` here: http://ideone.com/BS0xHR

Comment: use this instead: #include <algorithm>
     
    QByteArray reverse = seq;
    std::reverse(reverse.constBegin(), reverse.constEnd());

Comment: @danics Your solution is the best one can you add that as an answer? Or if you don't feel like it I'll edit my solution.

Comment: @danics There is an error, that in the <algorithm> you cannot give a constant a value. Do I have to change something in the Code?

Comment: @danics never mind 

When I open the programm everything is ok, but when I try to get the camera, the program crashs. And it gives me the warning, that std::Reverse_copy is unsafe.

Comment: @Der_Pätti, why you think problem is reverse operation may be your data assigned to QByteArray isn't valid any more in first position, write some code

Comment: QActionGroup *videoDevicesGroup = new QActionGroup(this);
    videoDevicesGroup->setExclusive(true);
    foreach(const QByteArray &deviceName, QCamera::availableDevices()) {
        QString description = camera->deviceDescription(deviceName);
        QAction *videoDeviceAction = new QAction(description, videoDevicesGroup);
        videoDeviceAction->setCheckable(true);
        videoDeviceAction->setData(QVariant(deviceName));
        if (cameraDevice.isEmpty()) {
            cameraDevice = deviceName; QByteArray cameraDevice; camera = new QCamera(cameraDevice); thats what it looked like before

Comment: You can choose in the menu witch camera you want to show.

Comment: @Der_Pätti Please make future comments on [danics](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4202858/danics) answer rather than mine for the clarity of any future viewers of this question.